# Android service is running only when app is opened otherwise giving error

Tags: android, google-maps, location, android-service, android-json

I am updating location details on server using service and it works fine if my app is opened otherwise it is giving error in service's starting time.."Unfortunately your app has stopped."

```
package com.example.friendlocation;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair; 
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UpdateLocationService extends Service {

String url = "http://znsoftech.com/googlemap/new/location.php";
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
String id;

 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In onCreate()!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId){
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In onStart()!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getresult();
 }

  private void getresult() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("location", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        id=sp.getString("id", null);
        if(id!=null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In id!"+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             LocationManager lm=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
             Criteria c=new Criteria();
             String provider=lm.getBestProvider(c, false);
             lm.requestSingleUpdate(provider, new LocationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", location.getLatitude()+""));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longi", location.getLongitude()+""));
                    JSONObject json=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST", params);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In onLocationChanged()!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        int success = json.getInt("success");
                        if (success == 1) 
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated in Service!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            stopSelf();
                        }
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not updated in Service!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in JsonException Service!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        stopSelf();
                    }
                }
            },null);
        }
 }

 @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    if(intent==null || intent.getAction()==null)
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In onStartCommand()!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    getresult();
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

 @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

 }
```

Added all permission in AndroidManifast.xml file. Where I am doing wrong? Should i have to use AsyncTask to update location in background?

Answer (score 0):

If its because of NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION then please do add null safety for location object.I had faced similar kind of problem in nexus device.
       if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

Comment: ok let me check...but location can't be null in the given method. check my code. i am using update listener.

Comment: can u post the logcat to figure out the exact issue